# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "-- " syntax error code 1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I run the below query on my database, it gives me the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "--,COUNT(*) FROM .. with 
syntax error code 1
```

Here's my query:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
final String MY_QUERY="SELECT d.* FROM deseases d where d.deseaseID in (select s.deseaseID  --,COUNT(*) FROM (select distinct deseaseID, syntomDescription FROM syntoms ) S where s.syntomDescription in ("+symptoms+") group by s.deseaseID having COUNT(*)="+symptomCount+") and d.deseaseID in (select m.deseaseID FROM (select distinct deseaseID, morphologyName  FROM morphology ) m where m.morphologyName  in ("+morphology+") group by m.deseaseID having COUNT(*)="+morphologyCount+" ) and d.chapterID  = "+category;

Cursor c =  db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remove -- before the ,(comma).....`select s.deseaseID ,COUNT(*) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original query probably had a newline after the COUNT(*).

Remove the entire comment, i.e., `--,COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 3):

`--` starts a comment in SQL. The SQL before the comment does not make up to a syntactically valid query.

It's not clear what you actually want to achieve, but removing the `--` would probably make it syntactically valid.

Comment: now it starts giving : (1) only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression